# PHP : Google Oauth - error in JWT - explode() expects parameter 2 to be a string

Tags: php, oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm in the process of modifying a login script to use Google OAuth authentication using the Google API PHP Client Library on PHP v5.6.

Code is based on the [idtoken](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/examples/idtoken.php) example on GitHub

It was almost there until I get the following error twice:
PHP Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /...../cendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php on line 65.

Using this method as main objective is to authenticate users of certain Google Apps for Work domains using the hd claim in the token.

My code section is as follows:

```
if($client->getAccessToken()){
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    $ticket = $client->verifyIdToken($token);
    if($ticket) {
        $data = $ticket->getAttributes();
        $userId = $data['payload']['sub'];
        $email = $data['payload']['email'];
        $hd = $data['payload']['hd'];
```

etc...

Scope has been set to 'email'.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Script is working now. Seems to be a problem with getAttributes. Printing $ticket, the result of verifyIdToken(), produces the array in the format expected - so no need for getAttributes.